# Angular routing including auth guard and redirections

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, url-routing, angular-routing

I have an angular app and want to implement client side routing. I have 3 components: `login`, `chat` and `admin`. Access to admin and chat is restricted by an auth guard. Ideally the **routing behavior should be**:

- **click login -> route to login and redirect to admin**
- **click admin or chat -> route to login and redirect on successful login to the clicked on (admin or chat respectlively)**

I managed to setup the redirections nearly correct, but the redirection when clicking login still depends on where I clicked before/last. Meaning that if the user clicks on login it will goto login and on successful login it redirects to chat. The user then logs out and clicks login, it goes to login but redirects to chat instead of admin, which I don't want. Clicks on login should always go to admin regardless of which route was active in past.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

## app.component

```
<nav>
  <ol>
    <li><a routerLink="/login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/admin">Admin</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/chat">Chat</a></li>
  </ol>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

## Login component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {AuthService} from "../auth.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  email: string;
  password: string;
  loginMessage: string;
  loginForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
      'email': new FormControl(this.email, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.email
      ]),
      'password': new FormControl(this.password, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(2)
      ])
    });
    console.log('init');
  }
  logout(): void {
    this.authService.loggedIn = false;
  }
  login(): void {
    if (!this.isValidInput()) { return; }

    const data = {email: this.email, pass: this.password};
    this.authService.login('localhost:3000/login', data).subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.loginForm.reset();
      this.authService.loggedIn=true;
      let redirect = this.authService.redirecturl ? this.router.parseUrl(this.authService.redirecturl) : '/admin';
      this.router.navigateByUrl(redirect);  
    });
  }

  isValidInput(): Boolean {
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      this.email = this.loginForm.get('email').value;
      this.password = this.loginForm.get('password').value;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm">
  <!-- this div is just for debugging purpose -->
  <div id="displayFormValues">
    Value: {{loginForm.value | json}}
  </div>

  <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
  <input id="email" type="email" formControlName="email" email="true" required>
  <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
  <input id="password" type="password" formControlName="password" required>
  <button (click)="login()" routerLink="/admin" routerLinkActive="active">Login</button>
  <div id="loginMessage">{{loginMessage}}</div>
</form>
```

## admin component

```
<p>admin works!</p>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css']
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

## chat component

```
<p>chat works!</p>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.component.css']
})
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

## authgauard

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor() {
  }

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    let url: string = state.url;

    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.authService.redirecturl = url;
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }

}
```

## app-routing module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ChatComponent } from './chat/chat.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'chat',
    component: ChatComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: true})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

## auth service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { throwError, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  redirecturl: string; // used for redirect after successful login
  username: string;
  loginMessage: string;
  greeting = 'Hello guest!';
  loggedIn = false;
  config = {
    serverHost: 'localhost',
    serverPort: 3000,
    loginRoute: 'login',
    standardGreeting: `Hello guest!`,
    standardUsername: 'Guest'
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(loginUrl: any, body: { pass: string }) {
    return this.http.post(loginUrl, body, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }

  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.loggedIn;
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: could you provide online example, please?

Comment: You're not using your authService redirecturl? In your login html don't automatically go to /admin `routerLink="/admin"` but use the authService.redirecturl when succesfully logged in. If it's not set, navigate to /admin in code.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I'll update the sample to be working.

Comment: @Carsten Sorry, I deleted this part for MCVE. I am doing what you suggested (see updates login code) but the issue is not that it is not redirecting but that it depends on what route was selected previously. It is just relevant when user clicks chat, redirect to login, log in successful, goes to chat, logs out, clicks login,  logs in successfully and gets redirected to chat instead of admin. (If he clicks on login I always want redirect to admin)

Comment: @simpleDmitry I added the service. I hope it works now. App-module and the rest is just standard boilerplate.

Comment: @avermaet Obviously set `this.authService.redirecturl = null` after succesfull redirect otherwise it will keep redirecting to the previous set redirecturl.....

Comment: @Carsten Thanks again. Additionally to the answer also your comments helped `resolve` :-) this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this  `<button (click)="login()" routerLink="/admin" routerLinkActive="active">Login</button>` in html  put redirection url in typescript like this.

```
    login(): void {
        if (!this.isValidInput()) { return; }

        const data = {email: this.email, pass: this.password};
        this.authService.login('localhost:3000/login', data).subscribe((response: any) => { 
       if(response.isSuccess){
          this.loginForm.reset();
          this.authService.loggedIn=true;
           if(!this.authService.redirectUrl){
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/admin');  
            } else{
             this.router.navigateByUrl(this.authService.redirectUrl);  
            }
         }
        });
      }
```

and If you are navigating to Login URL then please remove redirectUrl other wise it will always redirect to last visited page.

**EDIT**

In App.component.html you are navigating to login using routerlink instead of that use this

```
<nav>
  <ol>
    <li><a (click)='redirectToLogin()'>Login</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/admin">Admin</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/chat">Chat</a></li>
  </ol>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and in app.component.ts use this

```
redirectToLogin(){
    this.authService.redirectUrl = null;
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the last sentence removal of redirecturl on login?

Comment: Whenever you are redirecting to login page using router.navigateByUrl or routerlink then remove this.authService.redirectUrl for better use (Just being precautionary)